# JSON string with some html tag failing at parse

Tags: php, javascript, json, multilinestring

I am taking user input sending it to server using jQuery ajax...after inserting user values in database I am sending response back to client as JSON string as following

> echo '{"success":"true","data":"'.nl2br($a).'","type":"text"}';

as user input can contain new line, I am using nl2br so that all new line characters are converted to <br> and  also know that JSON doesnt support multi line, thats why I am using nl2br....but parsing is failing at client side

pls tell me what the reason and how can I solve it?

parsing code `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);`

Comment: Could you show the full response as received by the client?

Comment: what is the error you get on client side?

Comment: `{"success":"true","data":"adad<br>
dadad","type":"text"}` this my response at client side

Comment: That is valid JSON, what parsing error do you get?

Comment: doesnt show any error....but anything ahead parsing line is not getting executed,,,that parsing statement is not getting executed

Comment: When you log the JSON string in the console on the client side, does it log exactly the JSON you pasted? Could you show the parsing code?

Comment: `jQuery.parseJSON('{"success":"true","data":"adad<br> dadad","type":"text"}')` works fine, wich suggests that the JSON your client recieves is not what you pasted. Are you sure the code gets executed at all?

Comment: yes....code next to parsing line is not executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using json_encode, wich will generate a JSON string that contains `\r\n` for line breaks. Then you will have to replace each `\r\n` occurences by `<br>` tags.

```
echo str_replace('\r\n','<br>', json_encode(array("success"=>"true","data"=>$a,"type"=>"text")));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo json_encode(array("success"=>"true","data"=>$a,"type"=>"text")
```

Use the php function json_encode rather then trying to set the encoding yourself. You'll save yourself a lot of trouble that way. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I am getting this string as response `{"success":"true","data":"dada\r\ndada\r\nada","type":"text"}` i think here I need to replace all \r\n to <br>....??

Answer (score 1):

[nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) does not replace the line breaks, only inserts `<br>` before them.

As such, `\n` is being returned and therefore creating invalid JSON.

You should use `json_encode()` when creating JSON strings. For simplicity, you could simply use it on `data`:

```
echo '{"success":"true","data":' . json_encode(nl2br($a)) . ',"type":"text"}';
```

Comment: Ok let me try first that...I will get back to you

Comment: I am getting this `{"success":"true","data":"dada<br \="">\r\ndada<br \="">\r\nada","type":"text"}`